# How to boot in recover with Acer DA220HQL

Tags: fastboot

I would like to ask if there is any step by step guide to follow in order to get into boot recovery mode (Acer DA220HQL running Android 4.0.4). Additionally is there any specific version of TWRP suitable for this device?

Your help would be convenient to me!

Regards

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/root-and-custom-cwm-recovery-for-vsd220.2164736

Comment: have you installed this TWRP successfully?

Comment: Thanks for your helpful posts. Since there is no custom Rom for this specific model, it is pointless. In case you could find a suitable custom rom, I would be delighted and of course expect your additional help of how to safely install it step by step. Regards and happy New Year.

Comment: i wouldn't say pointless as you at least are able to root and customize the current Android 4.0.4 little. i am also running stock ROM on my two devices, just rooted and extended storage with external MicroSD Card